# Unable to update Anaconda packages on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: package-management, python, sudo, anaconda

The following message is being displayed whenever I am attempting to update any package with `conda update package-name`

I have installed Anaconda previously on 16.04 and 16.10 with no such issues.

```
CondaIOError: IO error: Missing write permissions in: /home/samriddhi/anaconda3
#
# You don't appear to have the necessary permissions to update packages
# into the install area '/home/samriddhi/anaconda3'.
# However you can clone this environment into your home directory and
# then make changes to it.
# This may be done using the command:
#
# $ conda create -n my_root --clone=/home/samriddhi/anaconda3
```

Comment: Check permissions with `ls -al /home/samriddhi/anaconda3`

Comment: . . . or `namei -l /home/samriddhi/anaconda3` to see the parent permissions also

Comment: > f: /home/samriddhi/anaconda3
> drwxr-xr-x root      root      /
> drwxr-xr-x root      root      home
> drwxr-xr-x samriddhi samriddhi samriddhi
> drwxr-xr-x root      root      anaconda3

Comment: So there you are that's the problem, root owns it

Comment: Mine is `drwxrwxr-x 20 george george 4096 Mar 18 09:02 anaconda2/`

Comment: What should I do install as non-root?

Comment: Remove that `/home/samriddhi/anaconda3`, run the installer `bash Anaconda3-4.2.0-Linux-x86_64.sh` from then on run the conda command without sudo prefix. Please note the `.sh` installer may not be the latest download the latest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common issue online and I found no solution for it on AskUbuntu or StackOverflow and hence I am posting this answer.

Anaconda comes as a ***.sh*** file which is to be installed with the following command

```
bash Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Now even though I have done it before for some reason I added a sudo before this command rendering the anaconda3 folder inaccesible without root permission.

Therefore the conda package management system could not access the directory and hence the issue.
If such an issue exists simply delete the previous installation instance with `sudo rm -rf anaconda3` and reinstall.

Thanks to [George](https://askubuntu.com/users/459561/george) for his valuable comments!

Answer (score 5):

Though Djokester's answer should work fine, it seems like terrible overkill to me.
One could just do:

```
sudo chown -R username:username anaconda3
```

Where username is your users name.